# How to create Jar File dependent on exe? Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation, selenium-edgedriver

I have written a Java selenium web automation code and I want to create a JAR for the same java code. Initially, I have hardcoded web-driver dependency like this:

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "EdgeDriver/msedgedriver.exe");
```

Now, If I create a JAR it will not work because we cannot run exe from JAR. I will really appreciate if someone can help me out.

Thank You

Comment: The code will work just fine as is.  (as long as the driver is in the path you set in setProperty)  Are you asking how to package the driver with your JAR?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean like how to package the driver with JAR.

Comment: You can add it as a resource and then extract it at run-time.  (You would then know the path because you put it there...)  I just put it in a folder called "Resources" (in src/.../).  Check "getResourceAsStream": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-

Comment: if you don't want to bloat your JAR file, there's always webdrivermanager which will download it at run-time if needed.  (It'll also manage your updates...)